# How to compute the median of a continuous distribution?

Tags: self-study, density-function, continuous-data, cumulative-distribution-function, median

I don't have a solid background in statistics so the concept of probability density functions in the statistics course I'm taking is new to me.
I need to derive the median of a continuous distribution with the following density function:

$$ f(x) = 2x^{-2}\mathbb{I}_{[2,\infty)}(x) $$

I computed the CDF which is $-2/x$ and I came up with the following answer: -4. However I don't think a negative median is possible. Could you please clarify how to derive the median of a continuous distribution?

Comment: A median less than zero certainly is possible in general. For your PDF, it is not, so you are correct to think you made a mistake. Please post your calculus for us to examine and help you got on the right track.

Comment: A negative median would be possible for a distribution that allowed negative $x$ (which your case does not). But a negative *probability* is never possible: the CDF is a probability, so must be between $0$ and $1$. This suggests you are missing an [integration constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_of_integration).

Comment: I equated the CDF which I derived from the PDF, -2/x + C, to 0.5. I recalled that we should disregard the integration constant since it could be any value.

Comment: You probably made a typo $f(x) = 2x^{-2}\mathbb{I}_{[2,\infty)}(x)$ instead of $f(x) = 2x^2\mathbb{I}_{[2,\infty)}(x)$

Comment: My bad. I fixed the typo introduced when I edited this post.

Answer (score 2):

You computed the CDF by using the proper integral of the PDF

$$\int 2x^{-2} dx = \frac{-2}{x} + C $$

But what you forgot is to use the correct integration constant (or use a definite integral).

---

Your CDF is not

$$F(x) = \frac{-2}{x}$$

But instead

$$F(x) = \begin{cases} 0 &\quad \text{if} \quad x \leq 2 \\
 \int_2^x 2u^{-2} du = 2 - \frac{2}{x} &\quad \text{if} \quad x > 2\end{cases}$$

---

You can see this intergral also like this (split up in two parts to eliminate the $\mathbb{I}$ indicator function):

$$\int_{-\infty}^x 2u^{-2}\mathbb{I}_{[2,\infty)}(u) du = \int_{-\infty}^2 0 \, du + \int_{2}^x 2u^{-2} du $$